# Dev -Cpp Compiler Build error

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I can't seem to find any thing on how to fix this and i have used Dev-Cpp befor but have never had this problem.I have tried re-installing Dev-Cpp and MinGW but nothing seems to work.

```
i:\gw\lib\crt2.o(.text+0x8) In function `_mingw_CRTStartup'

[Linker error] undefined reference to `__dyn_tls_init_callback' 

[Linker error] undefined reference to `__cpu_features_init' 

i:\gw\lib\crt2.o(.text+0x8) ld returned 1 exit status 

C:\workspace\cpp\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Project1.exe] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it can't find the MinGW libraries.

Click on `Tools -> Compiler Options`
In the directory tab, right click `Libraries` and change to the MinGW lib directory.  [In this example](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/dev-c-compier-just-not-working-/24305.html), it was `C:\MinGW\lib`

This might happen if you uninstall, re-install, or upgrade MinGW.

Comment: I have the similar problem but your solution doesn't solve my case.

Answer (score 0):

if you have install **Migwin or cygwin** in C then try to install Dev C++ on other directory with latest version. Old version on another directory will still may give you the same error.
My problem has been resolve by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error similar to this in Dev-Cpp (4.9.9.2) after installing MinGW32.

[Linker error] undefined reference to `__dyn_tls_init_callback'

[Linker error] undefined reference to `__cpu_features_init'

Apparently Dev-Cpp was automatically linking to those new libraries and I just changed the name of the MinGW32 folder (default location was inside C:). This fixed the whole problem and Dev-Cpp went back to linking the correct libraries when C:\MinGW32 was not accessible. Changing the Dev-Cpp compiler options library did not work in this case.