# I am doing a simple database management project in C .but when i run this code i get error .

Tags: c

i am trying to compare the filename given by user with the array of strings.when i run this code i get error as:
   In function `add_record':
   syntax error before ']' token

also,even if i remove the code from 'start' to 'stop' i get error as:
 i:\gw\lib\crt2.o(.text+0x8)  In function `_mingw_CRTStartup':

 [Linker error] undefined reference to`__dyn_tls_init_callback'
 [Linker error] undefined reference to `__cpu_features_init'
 i:\gw\lib\crt2.o(.text+0x8) ld returned 1 exit status

Please help me.Thank you!

```
void add_record()
{
 FILE *fp;
 char filename[25],fname_check[NO_OF_FILE][25];
 char tester;
 int i;

 printf("Type the name of the file you want to store the record in : ");
 scanf("%s",filename);
 //start
 for(i=0;i<sizeof(fname_check);i++)
 {
                                   if(strcmp(fname_check[i][],filename) == 0) printf("File already exists!\n");
                                   break;
                                   }
 printf("The file will be overwritten if you enter the same name.....\n");                                  

 printf("Type the name of the file you want to store the record in : ");
 scanf("%s",filename);
   //end                              

 fp = fopen(filename,"w");
 if(fp == NULL)
 {
       printf("Sorry,File cannot be opened!");
       getch();
       exit(0);
       }

 while(1)
 {
         fflush(stdin);
  printf("\nEnter name : ");
  gets(pro.name);
  printf("Enter age : ");
  scanf("%d",&pro.age);
  printf("Enter gender : ");
  gets(pro.gender); 
  printf("Enter phone : ");
  scanf("%d",&pro.phone); 
  printf("Enter email : ");
  gets(pro.email);
  printf("Enter location : ");
  gets(pro.location);
  printf("Enter bio : ");
  gets(pro.bio);

  printf("If you want to add more records press any key... or press ESC key... ");
  tester = getche();
  if(tester == 27) break;
 }
 fclose(fp);
```

}`enter code here`

Comment: `fname_check[i][]` is not valid, I think

Comment: [Linker error] undefined reference to `__cpu_features_init'
i:\gw\lib\crt2.o(.text+0x8) ld returned 1 exit status - have you told the runtime where to find all the shared .so/.dll assets it needs?

Comment: Unrelated, every time someone uses `gets()` , a kitten dies. It is so evil it has been removed from the standard library. Use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), or [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). The former is standard, the latter is part of gnu and POSIX.1-2008. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have commented the whole code still doesnt run... other programs are running fine though

Answer (score 0):

`fname_check[i][]` isn't valid. All you need is `fname_check[i]` which is a string.

Also, you have to loop until `i < sizeof(fname_check)\sizeof(fname_check[0])`, since `sizeof(fname_check)` will give the total size of the array in bytes.

Comment: i tried but this error comes again   i:\gw\lib\crt2.o(.text+0x8) In function _mingw_CRTStartup':

 [Linker error] undefined reference to__dyn_tls_init_callback'
[Linker error] undefined reference to `__cpu_features_init'
i:\gw\lib\crt2.o(.text+0x8) ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Then you must have linker errors. Probably because you didnt tell the compiler where to find the .so / .dll files it needs.

Comment: @Kishor your compiler can't find the libraries. What compiler are you using?

Comment: does it matter? other programs are running fine.. MinGW

Comment: @Kishor Configure your library location for your compiler. Perhaps [this could help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098217/dev-cpp-compiler-build-error)

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution... i had installed another mingw in my drive..i deleted one and everything works fine now...